# Keycloak: Spring Boot project as bearer and reusing token from user

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, authorization, keycloak

I am building an application with an angular frontend and spring boot on the backend. I was able to configure the angular and spring part.
So, the frontend requests a token and sends it with every request to the java backend. This works just fine.

My java backend is now in the need to reuse the client token to request data from another service, which uses the same mechanism.

What is the right way to go forward? Requesting an own token for my service or using the existing token from the authenticated user?

I have not found a way to do this.

Comment: While calling your 3rd service you can use the same token , Add your third service as bearer-only Client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works as pointed out by ravthiru

> While calling your 3rd service you can use the same token , Add your third service as bearer-only Client.